# Get the Title of all posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using Wordpress, Im also creating posts via XMLRPC based on an RSS feed that is added to periodically.

What I want is to read all post titles, compare those against the RSS feed, then only post to Wordpress where the post titles dont exist.

I'm trying this code:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-load.php');
query_posts('showposts=-1&author=1&post_status=publish');
?>

<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This gets all titles from `published` posts, I then need to do the same to get the `draft` posts.

I need to write these title's to an array?

Comment: So what's the question? Where's the code you're stuck on?

Comment: Updated question to ask to take the_title(); to an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be more efficient to write your own query to retrieve just the post titles rather than using `query_posts`. Something like this should work:

```
$titles = $wpdb->get_col(
    "SELECT post_title
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_type = 'post'
    AND post_author = 1 
    AND post_status IN ('publish', 'draft')"
);
```

Comment: fyi to anyone.. not sure if it version dependent, but i ended up writing and using this: `global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_name, id, post_type FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type IN ('post', 'page') AND post_status IN ('publish', 'draft') ORDER BY post_name ASC"  );
        print_r($results);`

Comment: There are very few instances where you would need to query the database directly, and this is not one of them.